# Are there some cases where みたす could be spelled as 充たす? 「充｛み｝たす」という書き方はどんな場合で使えるか？

Tags: kanji, spelling

Since 充 can be used to spell 充｛あ｝てる it can have the meaning of "to match". Therefore, the only place where I think 充たす fits is to say something like ある条件を充たす. Nevertheless, according to the 漢字漢和辞典 I looked up, 満たす can cover all the senses of みたす.

In what cases 充たす can be used?

---

「充」という漢字は「充｛あ｝てる」という単語に表れているから「一致」という意をも持っています。したがって、「充」は「ある条件を充たす」といった場合に使うことができると思ったが、調べた漢字漢和辞典によると、「満たす」という綴り方が「みたす」のすべての意を満たすから、かなり迷っています。

それで、「充たす」を使える場合を教えてもらえませんか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

充たす is less common and perhaps more literary than 満たす, because the kun-reading 充たす is not listed in 常用漢字表. Personally I don't semantically distinguish the two, and when I write something I always stick to 条件を満たす, エネルギーを満たす, 欲求を満たす, 幸福な気持ちで満たされる, and so on.

According to BCCWJ Corpus, 満たす is roughly 20 times more common than 充たす today. As far as I can see, all the examples of 充たす there were safely replaceable with 満たす.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that tends to confirm that both can serve for all purposes with no distinctions, except that 充たす is more rare.

Answer (score 1):

There is not clearly distinction between 充たす and 満たす.

But, there are some opinions of this distinction.

1)　満たす is used in mathematical use or when we pass over the borderline.
ex) 3名以上の人数を満たす
when something pours into container which has a decided capacity or volume(never change) , we use 満たす.

A glass is filled with water. →満たす(As the volume of this glass is　fixed.)

ex)条件を満たす
we pass over the suggested conditions.

Above of two examples are very similar.

2)充たす　is used when satisfied or in something not physical but mental (or invisible)

ex)心が充たされる

心　doesn't have fixed volume and cannot see . 
when filled with something (we think), as a flexible volume,the volume gets more.

充たされれば充たされるほど拡がっていく⇔The more we get, the more we want.

an　充たす is not  kanji for common use.

満たすは、一定のラインを超えること。充たす　は、一定の内容を備えること。

ともありました。参考になればと思います。

迷った時には　満たす　を使うか　ひらがなで記入すれば　まず問題なさそうです。

Comment: I think 心が満たされる is more common than 心が充たされる, and that I see 充 with 条件 more often than with 心.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any references (or examples from books) that support « 満たすは、一定のラインを超えること。充たす　は、一定の内容を備えること  » because the time 充たす used with 条件を充たす and I see it very rarely in other contexts.